# Divisibility problem. Prove or disprove if |c, then | or |

Tags: divisibility

I understand the problem very well. I just don't how to go at it.

Prove or Disprove: For all , ,  ∈ ℤ+, if |c, then | or |.

Comment: $12|3\times4=12$,  but $12\not|3,12\not|4$.

Comment: How to go at it: Write down three integers $a,b,c$. Check whether $a|bc$. If it does, check whether $a|b$ or $a|c$. Repeat with three other integers. Repeat as often as needed until you begin to perceive a pattern. Test the pattern with more repetitions. Try to refine the pattern. Try to find a counterexample. Or try to find a proof.

Comment: If a divides b times c does that mean a has to completely divide b or completely divide c?  What if part of a divides b and the rest of b divides c but the whole of a divides neither b nor c?  Is that possible?  What if $k|b$ and $j|c$ and so $a= jk$ and $jk|bc$.  Does it follow that $jk|b$ or $jk|c$?

Answer (score 0):

**Counter-example**: $$\large8|6\times 4$$ but $$\large8\not | \, \,6$$ nor $$\large8\not | \, \,4$$

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to realize that *maybe* $a$ can be factored to $a = jk$.  Then it's possible that $j|b$ and $k|c$ but those two statements are "unrelated".  It follows that $jk|bc$ but there is no "relation" between $k$ and $b$ or between $j$ and $c$ so there is no reason to believe either $jk|b$ or $jk|c$.

A counter example is easy to make:  Pick any two numbers where one divide the other.  Say $2|6$.  Then take another pair that are relative prime to both of these were one divides the other.  Say $5|35$.  Then obviously $2*5|6*35$ but equally obviously $2*5\not \mid 6$ (because $5 \not \mid 6$) and $2*5 \not \mid 35$ (because $2 \not \mid 35$).

(They don't have to be relatively prime.  You just need the factors of $a$ "distributed" among $b$ and $c$.  If $a = 4 = 2^2$ you can have $2|b$ but $4\not \mid b$ [say $b= 6$ and $2|c$ but $4\not \mid b$ [say $c = 10$].  Then you get $4|60$ but $4 \not \mid 6$ and $4\not \mid 10$.)

But what if $a$ is prime?  Then this **is** true.  $a$ can not factor so if $bc$ is a multiple of $a$ either $b$ is, or $c$ is, or both are.